# PHP syntax error when using 1===1 but not when 1===0

Tags: php

So I wanted to test a bit of code real quick and had a strange outcome.

[image]

Can someone explain why I got this?

*PHP version 7.2.7-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`1===1` results in the value `true`, which when cast to a string is `'1'`.
`1===0` results in the value `false`, which when cast to a string is `''`.

Your invocations are equivalent to `eval('1')` and `eval('')`. The first one is *incomplete* PHP code, since it's missing a `;`. The second one is simply nothing and does nothing. `eval` happens to return `false` as a result of doing nothing.

You must pass a *string* to `eval`, that's its entire point.

Comment: Nice one :) I should have included the explanation part of 1===1 and 1===0 in my answer I assume...

Answer (score 3):

[eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) should be called with quotes `""/''` which you are **not** doing. Assumedly its just luck that `false` works for some reason even though you are using the construct wrong.

The proper way to write it would be:

```
var_dump(eval("return 1===1;"));
```

Comment: Thanks, you were correct but @deceze's answer was just a touch more informative.  +1

Comment: @TolMera I agree. :)

Answer (score 2):

The PHP [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) () construct is used to evaluate an **input string** as PHP and then process it as such. Eval() is not a function, but it works like one in the sense that it outputs everything—except instead of outputting it as text, it outputs it as PHP code to be executed

Try

`var_dump(eval("1===1;"));`

Answer (score 0):

```
1 === 0 is false
1===1 is true
```

So you will get the same result if you try to execute this code

```
eval(false); //false equal to empty string so it don't throw error
eval(true); //true is not valid php code, thats why error throwed
```

Operators must be delimited with a semicolon

```
eval(1===1 . ';'); //this is valid php code
eval('1===1;'); //this is also valid php code
```